# Permission to modify files on desktop?

Tags: windows-7, permissions

When I try to delete files from my desktop or copy files to it I'm told that I don't have permission to do so, but I'm the administrator.  It's Windows 7.  I've seen something about anti-virus protection maybe being an issue and I have McAfee installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
right-click C:, click properties, click security, click advanced, click owner, click edit, select my username, and check 'replace owner on subcontainers and objects', and click apply, Try now

Comment: Seriously?  You want him to take ownership of every file on the C drive?  What about files and folders which have ACLs containing ACEs that reference `Creator Owner`?  All of a sudden those ACEs refer to you instead of the some other user.  That could break something.  I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Yeah, @Fran is right. Also, it'll pop-up with a lot of error messages too. Just use that method less globally, i.e. only on certain folders.